# API Gateway resource policy allowing invocation just from another API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have 2 API Gateways:

- arn:partition:apigateway:region::/apis/123
- arn:partition:apigateway:region::/apis/456

I want to restrict all type of access just allowing invocation between them.
So, API with id 123 can invoke API with id 456, and vice-versa. But not other services nor principals (IAM users or anonymous users). I want to restrict the invocation just to those APIs.

I thought about using resource policy but I don't have experience and In the examples AWS provides, it is not clear what should I do: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html

Can anyone help? I'm trying to learn different ways of securing resources. thanks

Comment: try hosting api's in private vpc .In private vpc resouces can access only those components which are in same vpc